# cuda triple riemann sum

Tags: cuda

I am trying to perform a triple riemann sum via cuda.  I am trying to use the multidimensional grid iterators for my sum iterators to avoid nesting loops.  I am using a 2.0 telsa card so I am unable to use nested kernels.

It does not appear that I am getting a full 0 -> N iteration for each of the x,y,z variables I need.

```
__global__ void test(){
uint xIteration = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
uint yIteration = blockDim.y * blockIdx.y + threadIdx.y;
uint zIteration = blockDim.z * blockIdx.z + threadIdx.z;
printf("x: %d * %d + %d = %d\n y: %d * %d + %d = %d\n z: %d * %d + %d = %d\n", blockDim.x, blockIdx.x, threadIdx.x, xIteration, blockDim.y, blockIdx.y, threadIdx.y, yIteration,  blockDim.z, blockIdx.z, threadIdx.z, zIteration);
}
```

---- called by -----

```
int totalIterations = 128; // N value for single sum (i = 0; i < N)
dim3 threadsPerBlock(8,8,8);
dim3 blocksPerGrid((totalIterations + threadsPerBlock.x - 1) / threadsPerBlock.x, 
                   (totalIterations + threadsPerBlock.y - 1) / threadsPerBlock.y, 
                   (totalIterations + threadsPerBlock.z - 1) / threadsPerBlock.z);
test<<<blocksPerGrid, threadsPerBlock>>>();
```

---- output -----

```
x   y   z
...
7 4 0
7 4 1
7 4 2
7 4 3
7 4 4
7 4 5
7 4 6
7 4 7
7 5 0
7 5 1
7 5 2
7 5 3
7 5 4
7 5 5
7 5 6
7 5 7
7 6 0
7 6 1
7 6 2
7 6 3
7 6 4
7 6 5
7 6 6
7 6 7
7 7 0
7 7 1
7 7 2
7 7 3
7 7 4
7 7 5
7 7 6
7 7 7
...
```

Output truncated, I am now getting every permutation, for 0 < x,y,z < 7, but I need 0 < x,y,z < 127 when totalIterations is 128.  For instance, in this execution,  40 < z < 49, where it should be 0 <= z <= 127.  My understanding of the multi dim grid maybe wrong, but for a riemann, each iterator, x, y, and z must have values of 0 to 127.

Also if I make totalIterations > 128, ex 1024, the program dies with a cudaError code of 6, which I understand to be a launch timer expiration.  Kernel is doing nothing but printing, so I don't understand why it's timing out.  Running this on a secondary device seems to remove the issue for the moment.  We are using one of the teslas to run X, but a geforce is in the mail to become the new display device to free up both teslas for computation.

The printf(...) will be replaced by the execution of the function to be summed.

The idea is to replace the serial code version of

```
for (int i = 0...)
    for (int j = 0 ..)
       for (int k = 0...)
```

Also I am not sure how to store the function values, as it does not seem memory efficient to create a potentially gigantic (millions x millions x millions) 3D array and then reduce it, but to somehow concatenate the function value into some sort of shared variable.

---- device info (we have 2x these cards, output is the same for both ----

```
Device 1: "Tesla C2050"
  CUDA Driver Version / Runtime Version          5.0 / 5.0
  CUDA Capability Major/Minor version number:    2.0
  Total amount of global memory:                 2687 MBytes (2817982464 bytes)
  (14) Multiprocessors x ( 32) CUDA Cores/MP:    448 CUDA Cores
  GPU Clock rate:                                1147 MHz (1.15 GHz)
  Memory Clock rate:                             1500 Mhz
  Memory Bus Width:                              384-bit
  L2 Cache Size:                                 786432 bytes
  Max Texture Dimension Size (x,y,z)             1D=(65536), 2D=(65536,65535), 3D=(2048,2048,2048)
  Max Layered Texture Size (dim) x layers        1D=(16384) x 2048, 2D=(16384,16384) x 2048
  Total amount of constant memory:               65536 bytes
  Total amount of shared memory per block:       49152 bytes
  Total number of registers available per block: 32768
  Warp size:                                     32
  Maximum number of threads per multiprocessor:  1536
  Maximum number of threads per block:           1024
  Maximum sizes of each dimension of a block:    1024 x 1024 x 64
  Maximum sizes of each dimension of a grid:     65535 x 65535 x 65535
  Maximum memory pitch:                          2147483647 bytes
  Texture alignment:                             512 bytes
  Concurrent copy and execution:                 Yes with 2 copy engine(s)
  Run time limit on kernels:                     No
  Integrated GPU sharing Host Memory:            No
  Support host page-locked memory mapping:       Yes
  Concurrent kernel execution:                   Yes
  Alignment requirement for Surfaces:            Yes
  Device has ECC support enabled:                Yes
  Device is using TCC driver mode:               No
  Device supports Unified Addressing (UVA):      Yes
  Device PCI Bus ID / PCI location ID:           132 / 0
  Compute Mode:
     < Default (multiple host threads can use ::cudaSetDevice() with device simultaneously) >
```

Comment: First thing's first: what's the output you expect, and the output you are getting?  WHat is the value of totalIterations?  Does that mean total per dimension, or overall total (X*Y*Z iterations)?  Regarding the reduction, you are right -- you will want to reduce on the fly, not store to memory and then reduce.  A combination of shared and global temporary storage will be your best bet. But first you need to answer the above questions...

Comment: totalIterations is a single dimension (current X, Y, Z are all the same size).  I am expecting to get every integral value for xIteration, yIteration, and zIteration from 0 to totalIteration. I am getting varying values of each iterator with each execution, but never do I get a set of values that corresponds to every permutation of x,y,z.  Expectations would be for totalIterations = 2; a thread with each of the values of x, y, z.  One thread would have values of the iterators to be 0,0,0, then 1,0,0, then 1,1,0, 1,0,1, etc, until each permutation is executed.

Comment: When more detail is requested it's best to add that detail to the question (click "edit"). Can you post a specific example input, expected output, actual output in the question?

Comment: Sorry this is my first time posting a query.  Details added.  Currently there is no "input" or "output" for the function to be summed as I am just trying to prove I get each permutation.

Comment: When I run the code, it works fine.  If I linearize the 3D index to a single number, I get `totalIterations*totalIterations*totalIterations` unique values output. Are you sure you are missing rows in your table?  Try sorting your output to make sure there are no duplicates. I think you will find you are mistaken.  printf is not free; 1 billion printf calls is likely to exceed the watchdog timer. The z dimension of a grid is more limited in size than other dimensions, and some devices don't support 3D grids. Make sure you query your device properties to make sure you are launching a legal grid.

Comment: I updated the output I'm getting, but still not seeing totalIterations^3.  Is there a more logical way to do this, than a multi-dim grid? I am just learning this, obviously, so I want to do this the most sane way, learning correct principles from the get go, instead of learning bad habits.

Comment: In your kernel, calculate `uint i = x + y * (gridDim.x * blockDim.x) + z * (gridDim.x * blockDim.x * gridDim.y * blockDim.y);`, then instead of printf, use `output[i] = i;`.  `output` is an `int*` array you pass to the kernel, allocated with `cudaMalloc` to a size of `totalIterations^3 * sizeof(int)` bytes.  Then read back that array and it should be a sequence from 0 to `totalIterations^3-1`, with no repeats and no gaps.  That is proof that you are hitting every cell.  If not, something else is wrong, but that's what I get.

Answer (score 1):

I think as has been already mentioned that using printf in device code to validate that every element in an (x,y,z) array has been touched by a thread is unwise for large values of x,y,z.

I created the following based on your code to prove that every element x,y,z gets touched by a thread:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define DATAVAL 1
#define cudaCheckErrors(msg) \
    do { \
        cudaError_t __err = cudaGetLastError(); \
        if (__err != cudaSuccess) { \
            fprintf(stderr, "Fatal error: %s (%s at %s:%d)\n", \
                msg, cudaGetErrorString(__err), \
                __FILE__, __LINE__); \
            fprintf(stderr, "*** FAILED - ABORTING\n"); \
            exit(1); \
        } \
    } while (0)

__global__ void test(int *data, int dim){
  uint xIteration = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
  uint yIteration = blockDim.y * blockIdx.y + threadIdx.y;
  uint zIteration = blockDim.z * blockIdx.z + threadIdx.z;

  data[((((zIteration*dim)+yIteration)*dim)+xIteration)]=DATAVAL;
}

int main(){
  int *testdata;
  int *result;
  int totalIterations = 128; // N value for single sum (i = 0; i < N)
  int testsize = totalIterations*totalIterations*totalIterations;
  dim3 threadsPerBlock(8,8,8);
  dim3 blocksPerGrid((totalIterations + threadsPerBlock.x - 1) / threadsPerBlock.x,  (totalIterations + threadsPerBlock.y - 1) / threadsPerBlock.y,  (totalIterations + threadsPerBlock.z - 1) / threadsPerBlock.z);
  cudaMalloc(&testdata, testsize*sizeof(int));
  cudaCheckErrors("cudaMalloc fail");
  cudaMemset(testdata, 0, testsize*sizeof(int));
  cudaCheckErrors("cudaMemset fail");
  result=(int *)malloc(testsize*sizeof(int));
  if (result == 0) {printf("malloc fail \n"); return 1;}
  memset(result, 0, testsize*sizeof(int));
  test<<<blocksPerGrid, threadsPerBlock>>>(testdata, totalIterations);
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
  cudaCheckErrors("Kernel launch failure");
  cudaMemcpy(result, testdata, testsize*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  cudaCheckErrors("cudaMemcpy failure");

  for (unsigned i=0; i<testsize; i++)
    if (result[i] != DATAVAL) {printf("fail! \n"); return 1;}

  printf("Success \n");
  return 0;

}
```